# Spartacus CCv2 Build process for multiple enviroments

Tags: spartacus-storefront

We're currently setting up a Spartacus application running on CCv2 with three different enviroments (dev, stage, prod).

We are struggling to set the right OCC API Urls, within Spartacus, for the enviroment, I guess the way to go are enviroment variables, as this is Angular standard, but we couldn't find a way to match the enviroment vars to the corresponding system.

Is there something we're missing?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The OCC baseUrl can actually be provided by CCv2 automatically. This is [described in the docs](https://sap.github.io/cloud-commerce-spartacus-storefront-docs/configuring-base-url/).

It works like this:

1. Add a static meta tag in your `index.html`, with placeholder content
   `<meta name="occ-backend-base-url" content="OCC_BACKEND_BASE_URL_VALUE" />`
2. The placeholder will get replaced automatically by CCv2
3. Remove the static configured baseUrl in the Spartacus configuration, as this will take precedence over the meta tag (we're about to change this)

This is however the only configuration that is environment specific, the ticket referenced by Grin is indeed a feature that we like to add.

Comment: Thanks a lot Tobi, I'll give it a shot tomorrow!

Comment: Is there a difference between `OCC_BACKEND_BASE_URL_VALUE` as suggested in your docs link and `OCC_BASE_URL` as suggested on step 7 on the [ssr doc](https://sap.github.io/spartacus-docs/server-side-rendering-in-spartacus/#adding-ssr-support-manually)

Comment: I can't find the reference to the `OCC_BASE_URL`, so not sure what you mean.

Comment: that's true because @platonn already fixed that issue ;-)

Answer (score 2):

We faced the same issue in our project.

It is was already reported as an issue on [Spartacus Github page](https://github.com/SAP/cloud-commerce-spartacus-storefront/issues/5772) .

Comment: Already came across this Gitbhub Issue but was hoping there was already a solution out there which we just overlooked, thanks anyway

Comment: @grin you might benefit from this as well, please let us know.